# Paste with right-click in unfocused Windows console

Tags: windows-10, terminal, putty, console

By default, in **Windows 10** console, to paste a text with right-click I have to focus the console window first.

I'd like to reproduce the **Putty** console behaviour, where the text can be pasted to an unfocused window by right-clicking only once.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you could switch to **Windows Terminal**, which has this feature. It also supports tabs, and allows to work with cmd.exe, Powershell and ssh in the same window.

You can also set [other behavior](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/global-settings#selection-settings) to reproduce Putty even more.